# Electric razors (Philips OneBlade) onboard in carry-on luggage

Tags: air-travel, regulations

I wonder if I can bring a Philips OneBlade in a carry-on luggage while traveling by plane.

It is not possible to cut anything with the Philips OneBlade but I still wonder if it's forbidden since flight companies say:

- Volotea: ***sharp objects*** are forbidden
- Air France: *Blades and any sharp, blunt, metallic or non-metallic items that may be used as weapons (for example: (...) **razor blades**)* are forbidden
- Easyjet: *Objects with a sharp point or sharp edge(...) including **razor blades*** are forbidden

I didn't check all the flight companies but I'm pretty sure that they all say something similar about sharp items and razor blades...

Are electric razors, in particular the Philips OneBlade, allowed in cabin?

Comment: They are generally allowed, however my dad has had his confiscated before. The reason they have was that it was not from a generally known brand and they couldn't tell what was inside the razorhead. I guess sometimes weird situations just occur. My blunt nail scissors were also taken, yet my compass with a huge needle was fine.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Good point, it should be an answer. No matter what the official regulations say, you are at the 'mercy' of the interpretation of those regulations by the person inspecting your luggage, and you won't win an argument during checkin if they say it is not allowed. Disregard the two answers so far that say it is allowed and don't take the risk.

Comment: 1/ is it sharp? 2-3/ does it have a blade?

Comment: I've carried an electric razor (different unit, though) in my carry-on for quite a while, the only time it drew any interest was when I had a whole jumble of electronics and wires that security couldn't sort out.  (Family emergency, I had simply tossed what I needed into my bag, no careful packing.)

Comment: @dotixx the fact that you didn't accept any of the answers, thus not giving the future reader information on what actually happened (it passed security OK or not) is what now makes me wonder of which is the correct answer!

Comment: @gsamaras I didn't accept any answer as I never tried to bring it... I thought that it is not worth trying if it can end up by losing 30 euros ...

Comment: I did bring the "braun razor" with me, and everything was OK, from Munich to Athens. :)

Answer (score 11):

They are generally allowed, however my dad has had his confiscated before. The reason they have was that it was not from a generally known brand and they couldn't tell what was inside the razorhead. I guess sometimes weird situations just occur. My blunt nail scissors were also taken, yet my compass with a huge needle was fine.

And to quote Jan Doggen's comment:

> No matter what the official regulations say, you are at the 'mercy' of
>   the interpretation of those regulations by the person inspecting your
>   luggage, and you won't win an argument during checkin if they say it
>   is not allowed. Disregard the two answers so far that say it is allowed and don't take the risk.

If the razor is too valuable to you, don't bring it.

Answer (score 10):

These are razor blades, which are not permitted to be carried on board aircraft.

[image: Razor blade]
[image: Double edged razor blade]

Your Philips OneBlade is not a razor blade, but an electric shaver. These are generally always permitted as carry-on.

Comment: Might also be worth adding an image of a straight razor.

Answer (score 9):

http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=electric%20razor

Check or Carry-on

You are good to go. Even disposable razors are OK. But this:

[image: straight razor]

this is not good. And obviously old style straight razors which are basically a knife are an absolute no go as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the official Braun email contact, I got:

> Of course, our razors can be taken in an airplane. I recommend you to
>   take the device with you in your hand luggage. If you are still
>   unsure, please contact your airline.

which seems like a prophecy by Oracle of Delphi, but thought it would add up to the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly carry it in your hand luggage because it’s an electric shaver not a traditional blade shaver. I have one from Remington and never faced any issue in carrying in handbag.

Rather I would argue that carrying it in check-in bag can be a trouble because your electric shaver contains built-in battery? I just avoid keeping any battery or power source in check-in luggage.